# Definition of different States of Streams (C++)

Tags: c++, class, iostream, definition, template-classes

I know that `ios_base` has a declaration of states for streams like
`ios_base::goodbit`(error state)
`ios_base::ate`(file open mode state)
and many more.
What I'm interested in knowing is the definition of these member functions of `ios_base`
Are they a simple **class** or a **class template**?  How are they implemented? Which one is there parent class(if any)?

Comment: they are public member function

Comment: https://www.ssl.berkeley.edu/~jimm/grizzly_docs/SSL/opt/intel/cc_80/include/c++/xiosbase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are they a simple class or a class template?

They are actually `static constexpr` declarations nested in the [`std::ios_base`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base) class (as from [*the reference documentation*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate)):

[image]

> How are they implemented? Which one is there parent class(if any)?

As mentioned there, it's compiler implementation specific. Usually these are simple values without usage of a *parent class*.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is no total freedom in the implementation, but as one can see in screenshot they have to be bitmask type which has some constraints. But I am not even sure if this counts as a nitpick.

Answer (score 1):

They are not "member functions", they are just some constants.

As you can find in standard library headers, `goodbit` is a constant with type `iostate`, and `ate` is a constant with type `openmode`.

i.e. libc++ defines them in header "ios":

```
typedef unsigned int iostate;
static const iostate goodbit = 0x0;
...
typedef unsigned int openmode;
static const openmode ate    = 0x02;
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking they are [`BitmaskType`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BitmaskType) `constexpr`. Defined in [`ios_base`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base) namespace.

`Bitmask type` is defined in [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (this is c++14 working draft).

> **17.5.2.1.3 Bitmask types [bitmask.types]**
>
> *[...]* Each bitmask type can be implemented
>   as an enumerated type that overloads certain operators, as an integer type, or as a bitset (20.5).

This means, even though there is a [`bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) compilers still have some freedom how to implement it.

The precise definition of the members you ask about is defined in `27.5.3.1 Types [ios.types]`, and relevant points basically say they are bitmask types.